# How to know if the input field is non-empty in case of remember password

Tags: javascript, html, dom

In the login screen of my portal I have username and password `input`  fields. When the user does **save password** in the browser, they come auto-filled next time(expected behaviour).

Now, when I try to access the value of those fields in my `script`, it shows empty fields even when the fields have values.

```
console.log(document.getElementById('username').value); //gives ""    
console.log(document.getElementById('password').value); //gives ""
```

Surprisingly, when I tried the same on console it worked.

I have tried using `setTimeout` as well to introduce some delay but it doesn't work. I am not able to understand how **Google Chrome** fills those fields.

Comment: You accessing it onload/document.ready?

Comment: @epascarello, tried both `$(document).ready` and `$(window).load`

Comment: Shouldn't be checked at form sent instead? Why are you doing it when the page loads up?